# How to make status-bar untouchable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, statusbar

I am trying to make a lock screen for android, versions greater than honeycomb. I have been searching for a working solution since a month now but haven't been successful. I'll be specific about my situation.

- **In a specific activity I want the status bar visible but untouchable AT ALL**. In other words the user should not be able to pull it down.
- **I really don't want the solution where I collapse the status bar when my activity loses focus**. This doesn't work! I am still able to pull down my status bar after one or two tries on my Galaxy Note-2.
- **I don't want to put my activity in fullscreen mode**. That will hide the status bar but i want it to be visible.
- **I know it is possible**. There are threads saying it's impossible to do so. But i know it's possible to do so because there are other custom lock screens which implement the same. (eg. Dodol locker, locker+, etc.)

I would really appreciate a working code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Lets give this a try it will not make the status bar untouchable completely but it will stop it from getting dragged,First give permissions in mainfest file for EXPAND_STATUS_BAR

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

declare these variables in your activity :

```
// This will keep track of activity's window focus
boolean currentFocus;

// This will keep track of activity's foreground/background status
boolean isPaused;

Handler collapseNotificationHandler;
```

It will ask you to override the following method,override it

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    currentFocus = hasFocus;

    if (!hasFocus) {

        // Method that handles loss of window focus
        collapse_now();
    }
}
```

Define collapse_now Method

```
public void collapse_now() {

    // Initialization for 'collapseNotificationHandler'
    if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
        collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
    }

    // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
    // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
    // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not 
    // 'pause' the activity
    if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {

        // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
        collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'                

                Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                try {
                    statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Method collapseStatusBar = null;

                try {

                    // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                    // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                try {
                    collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Check if the window focus has been returned
                // If it hasn't been returned, post this Runnable again
                // Currently, the delay is 100 ms. You can change this
                // value to suit your needs.
                if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
                    collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100L);
                }

            }
        }, 300L);
    }   
}
```

Handle activity's Pause state

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Activity's been paused      
    isPaused = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Activity's been resumed
    isPaused = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you vish. But this doesn't help. I already mentioned i don't want this solution. I have a Galaxy note-2 on which I'am still able to pull the status bar down after one or 2 tries. I am looking for a solution where the status bar is completely untouchable. :)